What is the genetic composition of "Cemetery H" culture?
I was reading about post-Harappan cultures in India and I came to know about the "Cemetery H" culture in Harappa which was there in Indus Settlement after the Modern Harappan culture died out. From archaeology it was found that this culture was distinct from Indus valley culture and also the people of this culture were totally distinct from the Indus valley people(genetically) which indicate migrations of people from other regions. So I was interested to know where are these people from, are they the Indo-europeans?(which migrated to India after collapse of Indus civilization) or maybe people from other regions(ie. what are the genetic composition of these cemetery H culture). But I couldn't find any research article regarding this topic. So if anyone could give me any information regarding this topic I would be grateful.

Question about genetics and Aryans are going to be trollbait.   Please revise to include research and be very specific.

Sadly, the fuzzyness in this area that gives some ultra-nationalist trolls a playland is also the same fuzzyness that makes research on this time and place so fascinating to the rest of us (or at least me).

The question is simply unanswerable at this time.
A 2015 article surveyed what was then known about the skeletal remains at Harrapan burial sites, including Cemetery H. It concludes that "the origin and continuity of ancient Indian people has been the one of the main subjects anthropologists worldwide have discussed about; and it will remain as such, for the time being in the future."
Later, in 2019 genetic material was sequenced for the first time from an individual associated with ancient Harappan civilization. I've found no more recent studies along those lines, so it's unclear when (if ever) Cemetery H remains will be sequenced for comparison.

It took way longer than it should have to figure this out (and yes this was implied if not stated), but it looks like the remains sequenced in 2019 were almost certainly not Cemetery H. This based on the assertion in the paper that "all the characteristic features of the Harappan burial customs and features are present in the cemetery" vs. Cemetary H burials being "completely different from the Indus civilization". Also, their estimated date for those remains (28-2,300 BCE) predate CH by about a millennium. Lastly, CH practiced cremation, which I would imagine makes DNA extraction difficult.

That qualm being said, I think that makes the top line here even stronger.
